# Can Value Object have behaviour?

Tags: domain-driven-design, value-objects

I have a Value Objects - Money and ExchangeRatio. I want to convert one Money to another using ExchangeRatio. So is it good to build a convert behavior on Value Object ExchangeRatio like so:

ExchangeRatio.Convert(Money) returns Money.

Or should I delegate it to some Domain Service instead? In other words can I build a behaviour on Value Object that doesnt change its state but has some logic, mathematic or other different object creation(based on its state) in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing sounds perfectly reasonable to me.  Eric Evans uses an example of a `Paint` object in his book that does the same thing.  The `mixIn` method takes another `Paint` object as input and returns a new `Paint` object.

With the `Paint` sample he demonstrates *side-effect free functions* in the book.

Comment: Ok, becuase Paint only knows about Paint instances in his behaviour. Here ExchangeRatio knows about Money, so its different case.

Comment: I would put the convert method on the money object though as you are working with money, not with ExchangeRatio.
Thus `Money.ConvertTo(ExchangeRatio)`

Comment: Well, Radek, further on the `Paint` is further refactored to include a `Pigment`.  So the `Paint` *knows* about the pigment and uses a ratio internally.  So as long as the *closure of operations* business holds we should be good.  Anyway, as SneekyPeet has mentioned you could swop things around a bit as your example actually looks more like a domain service already ;) --- the answer still holds, though: you *can* have behaviour on your VO.